# Finding the element associated with a particular instance of dom-repeat

Tags: polymer

I have a custom element that generates a large monthly calendar on the page.  This is created with a pair of nested dom-repeats the outer one providing each week of the month and the inner one providing the days within the week.  Initially this starts out quite empty, but then a ajax request returns with data which fills in the model, providing considerably more data for each day.  When a user clicks on one of the days I will (just started to implement it) open a dialog box with much more information about that particular day.  I can position this dialog box just beside the appropriate day because the tap event has the target of the tap as a property, and I can pass that to the `positionTarget` property of the paper dialog.  I have done this elsewhere and it works a treat.

In this particular case the particular day can be selected by an optional parameter in the url, parsed by `app-route`.  So I also would like to open the dialog box, positioned correctly, when a particular url is entered.

I can easily locate the underlying record in the model used for the calendar, but the question is how can I locate the element that is associated with a particular part of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the solution to this is relatively easy.

On the element you want to get its instance of expose an attribute that means something, with a value that is unique to each copy of the element.  In my case it was "date"

so I had something like (simplified)

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{week}}" as="day">
  <li urlday$="[[day.date]]"> ... </li>
</template>
```

then in my code to select open the dialog I did

```
this.$.mydialog.positionTarget = this.$$('[urlday="' + date + '"]');
this.$.mydialog.open();
```