# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opened' of null ; iron-collapse not open ;

Tags: android, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, progressive-web-apps

I am using polymer iron-collapse element inside iron-list as demonstrated in git-hub sample [sample link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-card/blob/master/demo/index.html) everything is working fine expect collapse mode. Getting error when clicking for change toggle mode. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opened' of null**

**var moreInfo = document.getElementById('more-info');** getting null

```
 <div id="scrollable-element" style="overflow: auto;">

        <iron-list id="_list" items="[]" as="person" scroll-target="scrollable-element" style="display: none">
            <template>
                <div>
                    <paper-card>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <h1 class="feed_title">[[person.heading]]</h1>

                            <p class="feed_description">[[person.subheading]]</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-actions">
                            <paper-button class="button-blue"> Share</paper-button>
                            <paper-button class="button-blue"> Explore</paper-button>

                            <paper-icon-button
                                    icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-up"
                                    title="more info"
                                    onclick="_toggle()"
                                    style="float:right;">
                            </paper-icon-button>

                            <iron-collapse id="more-info" style="width:100%;">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent enim ante, tempus
                                eget volutpat ac, cursus ac ante. Nulla facilisi. Praesent sed lacinia ligula. Donec
                                malesuada nisl eget quam iaculis, vel placerat justo cursus.
                            </iron-collapse>

                            <script>
                                function _toggle() {
                                    var moreInfo = document.getElementById('more-info');
                                    var iconButton = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget;
                                    iconButton.icon = moreInfo.opened ? 'hardware:keyboard-arrow-up'
                                            : 'hardware:keyboard-arrow-down';
                                    moreInfo.toggle();
                                }
                            </script>

                        </div>
                    </paper-card>
                </div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you seem to forget that iron-list is in effect a repeating template and so there is NOT just one element that you can find with that id (itself not a good thing to repeat the same id over and over.

I had a similar problem trying to locate an item in a dom-repeat template, so asked this question and then found the answer in the following stack overflow question and answer.

[Finding the element associated with a particular instance of dom-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688132/finding-the-element-associated-with-a-particular-instance-of-dom-repeat)